# How to wait for messages from user pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

example of my code, but when the bot switches to another command, this remains
Is there an example of how this can be done?

````
async def test(client, message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    await bot.send_message(user_id, "write code:")
    @bot.on_message(filters.private & filters.user(user_id))
    async def get_code(client, message):
        code = message.text```
````

Comment: One way is defining steps(WRITE_NAME=1, WRITE_SURNAME=2, WRITE_CODE=3, COMMAND_1= 4, etc), and saving user to database with his step. When user sends message, you read data about that user and check what step he is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly install the `pyromod` module with `pip`.

Then reframe the code like this:

```
from pyromod import listen
from pyrogram import Client, filters

app = Client(...)

@app.on_message(filters.private)
async def snd_something(client, message):
    asking = await c.ask(chat_id, 'send something..')
```

With the pyromod library all you have to do is `from pyromod import listen`. You can access the text sent by the user by using `asking.text`.
You can get more details on this [Here](https://github.com/usernein/pyromod#pyromodlisten)